# Identify attachement meta data whose posts were deleted

Tags: wordpress, post, media, attachment

Some wordpress posts have been deleted few year ago, but their associated media is still in the file system.

Is there a way to identify attachment meta data whose posts were deleted, then delete the meta data and the files from the file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just run a SQL query if you have access to the database. Assuming that your database prefix is `wp_` you can `SELECT` the media attachments that have a missing parent by searching by `post_type` where the `post_parent` is not in the `wp_posts` table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 
  -- the attachments
  post_type = 'attachment' 
  AND (
    -- ignore anything without a parent
    post_parent != 0 
    -- filter on anything that has a parent that does not exist
    AND post_parent NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts)
  )
```

Replace `SELECT *` with `DELETE` to remove these posts from the database. If you don't have cascading deletes, you may also want to check the `wp_postmeta` table for any entries where the `post_id` does not line up to a `wp_posts.ID`.